# Open custom object new/edit page from custom button and pass parameters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, salesforce

Have a custom button on opportunity page. The custom object and opportunity pages  are configured with page layouts for new & edit pages not VF.I want to achieve the following:
  1) On click on that button for very first time want it to open up "new"page of the custom object. The second time on it should open up the "edit" page.
   2) I also want to be able to pass 2 or more parameters from the opportunity page to the new/edit pages, mainly for new page.

3) On "Save" on the custom object page want it to redirect to opportunity view page.

Please can you provide me sample javascript or better way of doing that. Thanks following Javascript that I have cause issues:

```
var oppId = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
If ({!Opportunity.PQQ__c})
{!URLFOR($Action.PQQ__c.New, null,
[

"PQQ__c.Name"="{!Opportunity.Name}",
"PQQ__c.Opportunity__c"="{!Opportunity.Id}",
"save"="1",
 "retURL"=URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View, oppId)
],
true)}

else{{!URLFOR($Action.PQQ__c.Edit, null,
[

"PQQ__c.Name"="{!Opportunity.Name}",
"PQQ__c.Opportunity__c"="{!Opportunity.Id}",
"save"="1",
"retURL"=URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View, oppId)
],
true)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass parameters like this:

```
window.location = "apex/yourCustomPage?param1={!Opportunity.Id}&param2={!Opportunity.Name}";
```

At the visualforce page you can directly accessing these params like this:

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.param1}
```

In controller:

```
if (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('param1'))
{
    yourVar = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1');
}
```

Open new window like this:

```
window.open("apex/yourCustomPage?param1={!Opportunity.Id}&param2=edit";
```